# how to include an external template as partial

Tags: templates, handlebars.js, gruntjs, partials, mustache

First of all, i'm using Handlebars and Grunt.

I want to use a generic/reusable partial template included in the main template.
It seems so easy, but every try was unsuccesful!

I have something like this (all templates are in the same folder `module/templates/`):

main.m:

```
<div id="main">
    {{> myPartial}}
</div>
```

myPartial.m:

```
<span>Hi everybody</span>
```

in the Gruntfile.js i have:

```
compile: {
    options: {
        amd: "true",
        partial: true
    },
    files: {
        "target/module-templates.js": ["module/templates/*.m"]
    }
}
```

but when i open the compiled html, in the console log i see:

```
Error: The partial myPartial could not be found
```

i cannot find any exhaustive documentation on how to achieve that!

any help??